# facebook_app_events plugin crashes when running on Android

Tags: android, facebook, flutter

At the moment I have my app fully functional and running on Android. Next step was to attach to it [Facebook app events plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events/example). Guideline on the plugin page is simple and easy, I just need to include it in pubspec file and add manifest code to it. The problem I see now is that my code that was running perfectly before regarding other plugins in main function is now throwing errors and I can't find the link between those 2 and the reason app crashes.

These are the errors I see:

```
E/flutter (22953): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel
plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

E/flutter (23312): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method read on channel 
plugins.it_nomads.com/flutter_secure_storage)

E/flutter (23312): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel flurry)
```

In other words including Facebook plugin broke shared_preferences, flutter_secure_storage and flurry packages. Any ideas why this crash is even happening with just importing another plugin to the project?

Worth mentioning what I've tried so far with no luck of resolving this:

- `flutter clean` doesn't work
- stopping the app and running it again doesn't work
- removing the app from the device doesn't do the trick

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the Facebook App ID meta-data should be **inside** of your `<application>` tag.

See the bottom of your pasted Android Manifest and change it to

```xml
    <meta-data
      android:name="flutterEmbedding"
      android:value="2" />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Second of all, I'm not sure if you just obfuscated your Facebook ID or if you mean that you literally put `app_id` as your Facebook App ID?

Your facebook App ID should be something like a string of 16 digits.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">1122334455667788</string>
</resources>
```